# Manipulating LogFormat in httpd.conf to strip a particular query parameter

Tags: apache, logging, format, httpd.conf

The apache webserver in my web application has a config like below

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \
\"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""            combined
CustomLog /var/web/log/access_log combined
```

Problem is the `%r` is showing the complete url along with its query parameters. Like below

```
http://myserver/path/to/resource?q1=v1&q2=v2&secret=no-one-sould-know
```

Is it possible to configure in such a way so that I can skip logging the parameter `secret` in the `access_log`? Or may be logging this specific query parameter by encripting or something like this?

Or it will also work if I can skip logging for this particular request that ends with `/path/to/resource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve it by using `setEnvIf` directive

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI \/path\/to\/resource secret
CustomLog /var/web/log/access_log combined env=!secret
```

Here `SetEnvIf` sets the env variable per request basis. Hence, when the `secret` is set in env, the CustomLog will skip logging.

Comment: Have you solution if each url contains query string we want to omit ?